# how to generate random numbers that follow skew normal distribution in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have probability density function of skew normal distribution.I want to generate random number that follow the skew normal distribution in matlab.

Comment: That's a starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Generation_from_a_probability_distribution

Comment: you are right but i need skew normal distributed random number.to get simply random numbers is so easy.

Comment: Have a look at http://azzalini.stat.unipd.it/SN/

Comment: thanks i have already looked at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't vouch for their performance/adequacy, but http://azzalini.stat.unipd.it/SN/ says the following, and has a link to a .zip file of MATLAB functions:

> The library has been ported to Matlab by Nicola Sartori. So far, this refers to update 0.21; hence facilities for the skew-t distribution are not included. A portion of the facilities for the skew-t distribution is however available via [a set of Matlab functions](http://azzalini.stat.unipd.it/SN/skt-matlab.zip) which have been written and made available by Enrique Batiz (Enrique.Batiz [at] postgrad.mbs.ac.uk)

Also see [this code](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=108175&page=1) which is in visual Basic, but should be easily portable. Relevant excerpt shown below. This uses RandNorm (also in the linked webpage) which is a pair of numbers from a unit normal distribution, and in MATLAB you should be able to use `randn(2,1)`.

```
Function RandSkew(fAlpha As Single, _
                  Optional fLocation As Single = 0, _
                  Optional fScale As Single = 1, _
                  Optional bVolatile As Boolean = False) As Single

    ' shg 2008-0919
    ' http://azzalini.stat.unipd.it/SN/faq.html

    ' Returns a random variable with skewed distribution
    '       fAlpha      = skew
    '       fLocation   = location
    '       fScale > 0  = scale

    Dim sigma   As Single
    Dim afRN()  As Single
    Dim u0      As Single
    Dim v       As Single
    Dim u1      As Single

    If bVolatile Then Application.Volatile
    Randomize (Timer)

    sigma = fAlpha / Sqr(1 + fAlpha ^ 2)

    afRN = RandNorm()
    u0 = afRN(1)
    v = afRN(2)
    u1 = sigma * u0 + Sqr(1 - sigma ^ 2) * v

    RandSkew = IIf(u0 >= 0, u1, -u1) * fScale + fLocation
End Function
```

Comment: @Amber: you ought to be able to do this on your own. I mentioned how RandNorm() can be replaced by randn(2,1). The rest of it is straightforward; `Sqr()` converts to sqrt()` and you don't need the `Dim` statements.

Comment: how can we generate random numbers using skew normal distribution in multivariate case?

Comment: please ask a separate question on that, as I have no idea.

Comment: if i calculate the location ,scale and shape parameter in terms of mean ,variance and skewness then how can i get the skew normal distributed random numbers